# Is there a way to exclude some hours on where clause SQL Server 2016?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2016

I'm trying to obtain the orders that had been posted after 16:30 to 06:00. I got this query

```
Select OrderID, OrderDateTime, OrderNumber from Orders where OrderDateTime between '2020-07-01 16:30:000' and '2021-05-31 06:00'
```

I'm trying to exclude for the hours from 06:01 to 16:29 on all days. Is possible to do that directly from SQL query ?

Answer (score 0):

> I'm trying to exclude for the hours from 06:01 to 16:29 on all days. Is possible to do that directly from SQL query ?

Just convert to a `time` and filter:

```
Select OrderID, OrderDateTime, OrderNumber
from Orders 
where convert(time, OrderDateTime) < '06:01:00' or
      convert(time, OrderDateTime) > '16:29:00' ;
```

That said, I suspect you really want:

```
Select OrderID, OrderDateTime, OrderNumber
from Orders 
where convert(time, OrderDateTime) <= '06:00:00' or
      convert(time, OrderDateTime) >= '16:30:00'
```

It depends on how you are treating the seconds.

Comment: Thanks for your help. And I learn something new today.